# php & html inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to add html tag and php code inside JavaScript script

this is my code

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(2);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";

function myDeleteFunction()
{
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(2);
}
</script>
```

I Want to add select tag inside cell1 and my select tag have option value from database 
this is the code for the select tag ::

```
<td>
    <select id="nlocation" name="nlocation" >
    <?php 
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `nlocation` WHERE `nlocation` != '$location' ");
        if(mysql_num_rows($res)> 0)
        {
            for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($res);$i++) {
                $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);       
                echo"<option value='$row[nlocation]'> $row[nlocation] </option>";       
            }
        }           
    ?>     
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: `myFunction()` is missing a closing curly brace (`}`).

Comment: What kind of data do you have in nlocation column ? Be careful if you have special chars, then you must escape your string with htmlspecialchars() : htmlspecialchars($row['nlocation']);

Answer (score 1):

Easy ! Replace

```
echo"<option value='$row[nlocation]'> $row[nlocation] </option>";
```

By

```
echo"<option value='" . $row['nlocation'] . "'>" . $row['nlocation'] . "</option>";
```

.

Edit : I haven't understood all your question .. You have to memorise values (under last echo) :

```
$arr_data[] = $row;
```

And, in your javascript :

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<?php echo $arr_data[0]['nlocation']; ?>";
cell2.innerHTML = "<?php echo $arr_data[1]['nlocation']; ?>";
```

Comment: ***Why*** does that fix the problem?

Comment: my problem is to add this selec tag in the cell1 in the javascript

Comment: Because $row[nlocation] not reffer to the nlocation index, but to the $nlocation variable .

Comment: i want to replace 
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1"; 
with 
cell1.innerHTML = (the html tag  select tag)!!!!

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen What he means is `$row[nlocation]` is invalid and won't work because it contains string. While `$row[0]` is valid, the string needs to have single quotes around it, thus `$row['nlocation']`. @user3315393 Can you explain what you are trying to do? I see no relation between your two blocks of code.

Comment: i want to add <select tag> inside  cell1.innerHTML = (the html tag select tag)!!!!

cell.innerHTML="<select ......."; !!!

Comment: @user3315393 If the select tag should be added on page load, then instead of `echo`, save it into a PHP variable and pass that PHP variable to JavaScript(they should both be on same page), if the select tag is dynamic, then use [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Actually, PHP would convert `$row[nlocation]` to `$row['nlocation']` (although it's strongly discouraged (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts) to make it do so). The actual issue is that PHP does **not** perform string substitution with arrays unless the string is contained in double-quotes and the array is escaped with `{}`.

Comment: @Tieson T. > I didn't know, thanks

Comment: @TiesonT. You're right, weird why I was determined it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is two methods:

Using points to add string : "foo" . $bar . "foo";

```
echo"<option value='" . $row['nlocation'] . "'> " . $row['nlocation'] . " </option>";
```

or (I prefer), use backets foo {$bar} foo

```
echo"<option value='{$row['nlocation']}'> {$row['nlocation']} </option>";
```

NOTE: I prefer the second option because we use ". So PHP will anyway look for vars into the string. If you want a faster script, be sure to use **'foo'** for every text.

Comment: Pleaaaaaaase this is not my problem !!!

my proplem is how to insert select tag into javascript function !!!!!!!!

in the code 

    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";

i want to replace "new cell2" with select tag 

only this problem

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to just assign the HTML content created by your PHP script to a JavaScript variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectContent = "<select id=\"nlocation\" name=\"nlocation\">" +
        "<?php 
            $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `nlocation` WHERE `nlocation` != '$location' ");
            if(mysql_num_rows($res)> 0)
            {
                for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($res);$i++) {
                    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

                    echo "<option value='".$row['nlocation']."'> ".$row['nlocation']." </option>";
                }
            }
        ?>" +
        "</select>";
</script>
```

And then just `innerHTML` the `selectContent` var HTML into your cell.

Edit: I'll attempt again to answer your question.

You cannot replace a  cell with a  form element. My previous answer assigns the dynamically generated select element and options to a JavaScript variable. From here you can insert the select code into your table cell as follows:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(2);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    // INSERTING SELECT CODE HERE!!
    cell2.innerHTML = selectContent;

function myDeleteFunction()
{
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(2);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Pleaaaaaaase this is not my problem !!!

my proplem is how to insert select tag into javascript function !!!!!!!!

in the code 

    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";

i want to replace "new cell2" with select tag 

only this problem